# Wanting 12.04 LTS day one reset to zero on celeron

Tags: 12.04, reset

Wanting to day one reset my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to day zero. I actually want to wipe everything, to say I made a mess some where is stating the obvious. My update manager says some updates must have not completed or I downloaded unsupported, I know I did a few. Clearing everything will eliminate any place a problem could be hiding.

I understand I can try a torrent, but all see is amd nothing about celeron 847 1.1 GHZ dual. Besides, didn't look at requirement but I don't know if I can just upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS due to my memory issue. i know Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is too much requirements. Having a ASUS 1015-e means I have to take apart and I don't want to do that if I don't have to.

I believe this covers everything about just upgrade hardware.

I also went to Ubuntu reinstaller, clicked the link and nothing is there.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuInstaller

Answer (score 0):

To reset to "day zero", you can simply install Ubuntu over again, using a DVD or USB stick (the same way you installed it in the first place). You can download 12.04 at http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ or 14.04 at http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

If you have an older, 32-bit processor, you may need the ...`-i386.iso` file instead of the ...`-amd64.iso` file.

When you boot into the Ubuntu installer, one of the options should be to erase the disk and install Ubuntu.

Comment: everything seemed to be working, lucky me everything came through 100%, no error in download. made a usb, again tells me i'm good. then i'm told, either there's an issue with download or wrong architecture.

Comment: I've tried 32 and 64 bit iso. With Ubuntu 12.04 LTS it went far as restarting and a blank screen for some time. A few hours I couldn't get past the GRUB menu, having to use a previous version every time I want to use my laptop. With the option to Factory state, and that not working I search the Internet for some time to no avail finding how to comment out/in a solution. Found out the version i booted into had no Wi-Fi, my only means of Internet access, i looked into it. No hardware existed according to the terminal. Solution was found for Wi-Fi not the GRUB. Tried Ubuntu 14.04, nothing

Answer (score 0):

The solution to both the original post and the problem with booting are the same. Long as the Hardware meets requirements, provided on site of most .iso downloads,these problems can be solved.

First obtain the desired OS .iso. Get to the desktop and transfer the .iso to home. Burn the .iso back to device. I kept the .iso on my USB in case something went awry. What should happen normally a window will pop up and follow instructions for installtion.

For me I had to have a Internet connection, otherwise install would revert back to previous settings. Added with the possibility during the hours of fetching packets someone had fun with my stuff, causing problems (see comment). Certain other factors lead me to believe that possibility.

Install not working and my now buggy OS didn't recognize the boot. Whats has to be done to fix all of this is open terminal and make the desired device with the .iso an option in boot menu. Shut down and turn back on in boot screen. Provided everything was done correctly, the option will be there, select device. Install/upgrade will work normally.